# How do you prove this determinant-related identity in geometric algebra?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I would like to show that

$$
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha i} F_{\beta j} \cdots F_{\gamma k} e_\alpha \wedge e_\beta \cdots \wedge e_\gamma I^\dagger
&= e_{\alpha} \cdot F(e_i) e_\beta \cdot F(e_j) \cdots e_\gamma \cdot F(e_k)  e_\alpha \wedge e_\beta \cdots \wedge e_\gamma I^\dagger \\
&= F(e_i) \wedge F(e_j) \cdots F(e_k) I^\dagger
\end{align}
$$

where $F(e_i)$ is a linear function of the vector $e_i$, and $F_{ij} \equiv e_i \cdot F(e_j)$. The $\{e_k\}$ are all orthogonal frame vectors. This is stated in Doran and Lasenby (4.202) pg 117, Geometric Algebra for Physicists.

Attempt:

$$
\begin{align*}
e_{\alpha} \cdot F(e_i) e_\beta \cdot F(e_j) \cdots e_\gamma \cdot F(e_k) e_\alpha \wedge e_\beta \cdots \wedge e_\gamma I^\dagger 
&=(?) \langle e_{\alpha} F(e_i) e_\beta F(e_j) \cdots e_\gamma F(e_k) e_\alpha \cdots e_\gamma  I^\dagger \rangle
\end{align*}
$$

It is not clear how to simplify this. I simply changed the dot products to geometric products under the scalar projection operator, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Your attempt is incorrect, that should be $$\langle e_\alpha F(e_i)\rangle\langle e_\beta F(e_j)\rangle\cdots.$$ You cannot just smoosh it all into a single scalar projection like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Doran and Lasenby say *orthonormal* frame vectors, not just orthogonal. Since $e_\alpha$ is an orthonormal basis and (from what I can tell) we are working with a Euclidean metric, it is its own reciprocal $e^\alpha$. Thus
$$
  (e_\alpha\cdot F(e_i))e_\alpha = e_\alpha(e^\alpha\cdot F(e_i)) = F(e_i).
$$
This follows simply by definition of the reciprocal basis and by expressing $F(e_i)$ in the basis $e_\alpha$.

Comment: Wow, this was easier than it first looked to me